# Flickery Mirror modifier or Render in 3.2.2?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, versions, mirror-modifier

I had to rerender some project files, but in the mean time I updated Blender from 2.93 to 3.2.2.

Now the render "Flickers" in the parts with the mirror modifier. (also in the File)

What happens to my side cutters?
Is there a solution? or is it a Bug?

Images from the same project file just diffent blender versions.

EDIT: Rendered Images attached

Blender 2.93 and Rendered Image
[image: Blender 2.93]
[image: 2.93 Rendered]

Blender 3.2.2 and Rendered Image
[image: Blender 3.2.2]
[image: 3.2.2 Rendered]

Comment: Please include the whole screen in your image. That way we can see your settings. Just your 3D view doesn't really show any problem. You can take a screenshot via the Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question and add the image to it.

Comment: You mean the dark parts on the pliers? There's double geometry, two faces lying in the same place. This is called Z-fighting when the renderer is struggling with which surface to show. I guess you've got some part of the mesh lying on the other side of the mirror axis so it appears mirrored in one direction and the other.

Comment: yes, that double faces in the middle of the pliers, from the modifier. I cant delete the faces because the pliers rotates.  I understand how the "problem" is created, but why the render has a problem in 3.2.2. I just need fix to work like in ver. 2.93